# OpenLayers seems slow when zooming / panning on vector (geometry line) from GeoJSON. Why?

Tags: openlayers-2, geometry, geojson, sql-server

I have a layer with 7 lines; when I zoom on some of the lines, the maps seems to be very slow.

I thought it might be because I bring a lot of points to the client (that represents the line).

```
aa
Line Id     Num of Points As Text
----------- ------------- ---------------------------
1           9971          MULTILINESTRING ((34.797771
2           13180         MULTILINESTRING ((34.808654
3           5465          LINESTRING (34.94746717 31.
4           5397          LINESTRING (34.94746717 31.
5           9550          MULTILINESTRING ((35.104847
6           3770          LINESTRING (34.94746717 31.
7           3770          LINESTRING (34.94746717 31.
```

Line 1 and 5 are very slow on the map... They are MultiLineString because I use MakeValid on the geometry from MSSQL.

Any Idea why this happens ?

Comment: Can you post a reproduceable example on jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: http://109.226.63.153/Taskir
Click on Id 1 on the bottom list to see when when map goes slow.

Comment: What browser are you using? Internet Explorer (especially 8 and older) can become a bit slow with complex vector objects, which is why we tend to use WMS instead. I didn't personally get any issues when using IE8 and Firefox. On IE8 it was initially unresponsive when I clicked on the list item but after that it was fine.

Comment: Using Chrome and Firefox. I want to be able to update the vector (split and union it)  , can i do it over WMS?

Comment: @Rob Quincey : I've tested it on different clients different computers , same results. if you click ID 1 on list and then after the screen zoom to the vector (highlighted in blue) than if you pan/zoom it goes very slow... unlike trip 2..4... etc..